# Request body is not read

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Hello i am faced with the following problem:

I am trying to issue a `http` `POST` request to a server expecting a list of objects ( json).
The request body looks like this:
`{"context":3}`.
If the request body is not read , the operation will not fail , instead it will return more objects ( the body acts as a filter).

I am trying to understand why the `request body` is not taken into consideration since i always get all objects.

```
[TestCase]
public async Task CanGetFromAws()
{
    var data = new { context = 3 };
    var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var content = new StringContent(raw);
    HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        Content = content,
        RequestUri =new Uri(URL)
    };

    var response=await client.SendAsync(msg);
    var payload =await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

From `postman` it works, the request body is read and i get the filtered result , i have also tried with `RestSharp` and again it works:

```
[TestCase]
public async Task CanGetFromAwsWithRESPSharp()
{
    var data = new { context = 3 };
    var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    var client = new RestClient(URL);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    request.AddParameter("application/json", raw, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var dt = response.Content; //gets filtered results
}
```

Could someone explain me what could be the problem , why does my request body is not considered in the first case?

**P.S** The `URL` is a `string` constant ,not relevant.

Comment: You don't set the `Content-Type` in that first example. e.g. `new StringContent(raw, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`;